# Grouping array elements based on range and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I got array elements containing unix time for Tweets of last week

```
times = [1383285836, 1383285835, 1383285827, 1383285819, 1383285819, 1383285818, 1383285814, 1383285808, 1383285806, 1383285802, 1383285793, 1383285787, 1383285781, 1383285781, 1383285781, 1383285779, 1383285778, 1383285756, 1383285756, 1383285755, 1383285755, 1383285753, 1383285752, 1383285752, 1383285746, 1383285739, 1383285735, 1383285735, 1383285729, 1383285721, 1383285717, 1383285715, 1383285715, 1383285712, 1383285710, 1383285708, 1383285706, 1383285702, 1383285694, 1383285690, 1383285690, 1383285689, 1383285689, 1383285684, 1383285684, 1383285682, 1383285681, 1383285681, 1383285681, 1383285680, 1383285670, 1383285670, 1383285663, 1383285659, 1383285659, 1383285658, 1383285656, 1383285653, 1383285650, 1383285648, 1383285647, 1383285647, 1383285644, 1383285641, 1383285639, 1383285636, 1383285633, 1383285632, 1383285627, 1383285625, 1383285623, 1383285622, 1383285620, 1383285620, 1383285619, 1383285618, 1383285616, 1383285612, 1383285612, 1383285607, 1383285607, 1383285607, 1383285603, 1383285602, 1383285599, 1383285594, 1383285590, 1383285588, 1383285586, 1383285574, 1383285572, 1383285572, 1383285568, 1383285568, 1383285567, 1383285562, 1383285560, 1383285559, 1383285557, 1383285556]
```

I want to group them by a range and their count so i get of how many Tweets per day

```
grouped = {date1: 3, date2: 1, date3: 5}
```

Thanks!

Comment: not clear that `1,3,5` values

Comment: Mohamed, did you intend to checkmark an incorrect answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this also

```
times.group_by{|x| x }.values.map{|y| y.count}
```

Comment: You need to convert seconds to dates before grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the unix time to date and then use `each_with_object` to group and count:

```
times.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)){|i,h| h[Time.at(i).to_date] += 1}
#=> {date1: 3, date2: 1, date3: 5}
```

You can also do:

```
 Hash[times.group_by{|i| Time.at(i).to_date }.map{|k,v| [k,v.size]}]
 #=> {date1: 3, date2: 1, date3: 5}
```

Comment: Awesome! So then I can do a .count for each right?

Comment: @Mohammed, you can map the result, replacing each hash value `v` with `v.size`.

Comment: I got this:   {Fri, 01 Nov 2013=>[1383283248], Thu, 31 Oct 2013=>[1383275391, 1383274659, 1383266019]

Comment: Sorry, @CarySwoveland how do I do that?

Comment: times.group_by{|i| Time.at(i).to_date}.map{|key,value| value.count}

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy that was incomplete, my bad. Updated the answer.

Comment: @tihom I got the same thing as `times.group_by{|i| Time.at(i).to_date}.map{|key,value| value.count}`  or if I used CarySwoveland's suggestion: times.group_by{|i| Time.at(i).to_date}.values.map{|value| value.count}

Comment: yes those would give you an array of count but not the dates.

Comment: Yeah that's what I want. Thanks :D

Comment: @tihom what if I want to range the array by time of day. So currently its by date, what if I want by blocks of the day (eg. Morning being 8am-12pm, Afternoon being 12pm-4pm, etc.)

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy can you add an update to your question explaining the second format. Try it yourself though first..it would be fun :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for the check...it has been a bad answer day for me!

Comment: Yes, I think Mohammed should now have little difficulty with any grouping of seconds.

Comment: @tihom I'll give it a try and let you know how it works ;)

Comment: @tihom I got to this `times.group_by{|i| Time.at(i).beginning_of_hour.hour}` but I can't seem to organize it by blocks of hours. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy try `Time.at(i).utc.hour/4` in `group_by` it will return an hash like `{0=>count, 1=> count....,6 => count}` in blocks of 4 hours, 0 for 12 am to 3:59am , 1 for 4 to 8 am...so on. `utc` is to use the time in utc timezone otherwise the results would be for local time zone.